# Why I can not open files to read or write in perl?

Tags: perl

I am learning Perl by using vs code.
I am trying to open file .pep and read from it but every time I get that the path is not found.
I have put the protein.pep and code.pl in the same folder.

here is the protein.pep file

```
MNIDDKLEGLFLKCGGIDEMQSSRTMVVMGGVSGQSTVSGELQD
SVLQDRSMPHQEILAADEVLQESEMRQQDMISHDELMVHEETVKNDEEQMETHERLPQ
GLQYALNVPISVKQEITFTDVSEQLMRDKKQIR
```

with path D:\bioinformatics\protein.pep

here is my code.pl file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$proteinfilename = 'protein.pep';

open(PROTEINFILE, $proteinfilename)or die "Can't open '$seq': $!";

# First line
$protein = <PROTEINFILE>;

# Print the protein onto the screen

print "\nHere is the first line of the protein file:\n\n";
print $protein;

# Second line
$protein = <PROTEINFILE>;

# Print the protein onto the screen

print "\nHere is the second line of the protein file:\n\n";
print $protein;

# Third line
$protein = <PROTEINFILE>;

# Print the protein onto the screen
print "\nHere is the third line of the protein file:\n\n";
print $protein;
```

and its path is ‪D:\bioinformatics\code.pl

I am getting this output "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: Is it this line `open(PROTEINFILE, $proteinfilename)or die "Can't open '$seq': $!";` that gives the error ? Btw. `$seq` is not defined

Comment: I would also recommend using [Three-arg open()](http://modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html) instead of old-style two-arg

Comment: it is not an error, it is an output

Comment: ok, but an error can also be output. Try to determine which line of the script is producing the output

Comment: i will attach a pic of code in my question, please check it

Comment: From your screenshot it seems the issue can be related to VS code. How do you run the script from VS code?

Comment: by the running icon on the top right.

Comment: i was using notepad and  Perl command line before vs code and it used to give me error in the output "readline() on closed filehandle PROTEINFILE at D:\bioinformatics\ex4-5again.pl line 8."

Comment: *"by the running icon on the top right"* Strange, I tried this on Windows 11 now and I do not get a "running" icon there, see [this](https://imgur.com/a/pFpp76U) screen shot. Did you install a debugging extension for Perl in VS code?

Comment: *"it used to give me error in the output"* Can you try run the script from the command prompt?

Answer (score 7):

You have in your code:

```
$proteinfilename = 'protein.pep';

open(PROTEINFILE, $proteinfilename)or die "Can't open '$seq': $!";
```

First, change the error message to tell you which file the `open` wants:

```
open(PROTEINFILE, $proteinfilename) or die "Can't open '$proteinfilename': $!";
```

You only give the `open` the relative path name. I bet it works with the full path name:

```
$proteinfilename = 'D:\\bioinformatics\\protein.pep';

open(PROTEINFILE, $proteinfilename) or die "Can't open '$proteinfilename': $!";
```

If you still have problems with that, post the actual output of the program.

## You aren't where you think you are

I'm guessing that the problem is with your IDE and the current working directory. A program does not automatically work in the directory in which you store it. You can use the `Cwd` module that comes with Perl to see where your IDE starts you:

```
use Cwd qw(getcwd);
print "I'm in " . getcwd() . "\n";
```

If you want your program to be in a particular directory as it does its work,

```
chdir $some_directory or die "Could not change to '$some_directory': $!";
```

You might choose that directory to be in the same as that of the program. The `FindBin` module that comes with Perl is handy for telling you where that is:

```
use FindBin;
chdir $FindBin::Bin;
```

## A bit more modern

Perl has various better ways of doing things even though it supports almost everything you could do 30 years ago. The three argument `open` that denotes the file mode is a bit safer. And, Perl v5.36 is about the disable user-defined bareword filehandles when you specify `use v5.36`, so get into the habit of using a lexical filehandle.

```
open my $protein_fh, '<', $proteinfilename or die "Can't open '$proteinfilename': $!";
```